# Add another column to ajax dropdown

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a series of chained selects that are populated dynamically by a call to a MySQL database.

> This works great but I have to add another column 'Invm_InventoryDesc' to the label but keep the value the same
>   (Invl_InventoryNumber) for each option in one of the selects.
>
> I tried to alter the query to include the Invm_InventoryDesc but it breaks it...what am I doing wrong?

```
default:
    if (strpos($key, 'brandSelect-') === 0) {
        $callType = str_replace('brandSelect-', '', $key);
        $resBrands = mysql_query('SELECT Invl_InventoryNumber FROM ' . DB_TABLE1
            . ' WHERE Invl_LocationId  = ' . mysql_real_escape_string($callType) . " ORDER BY Invl_InventoryNumber");
        $select = new SelectBox('What part number are you looking for?', 'Pick a part');
        for ($i = 0; list($brand) = mysql_fetch_row($resBrands); $i++) {
            $select->addItem($brand, 'result-' . $brand . '-' . $callType);
        }
```

Comment: You need to tell us what error you are getting. Code for the SelectBox class would be helpful too.

Comment: Sorry, basically the dropdown is empty, no error so its not creating the individual options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're not sharing the actual php error you get when executing your code i can only guess what's wrong.

I see you are using the for statement wrong.

i would suggest something like this, instead of you're current for loop:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_rows($resBrands); $i++) {
    $brand = mysql_fetch_array($resBrands);
    $select->addItem($brand, 'result-' . $brand . '-' . $callType);
}
```

Now the for statement actually does something.

The $i counts how many rows we allready added to $select. At first its 0 "$i = 0".

After this we check if the number of rows we allready added is smaller than the number of rows we need to add (the number of rows mysql gives us back).

Then we load a row to $brand. And add this to $select. (I have no clue what you're doing with $brand and $select so i stay with you're code.)

After this we add one to $i. And we start over again

It could be that you have more errors in you're code. but without more context i can't tell if there are more errors.